# unable to access res.locals.user variable in express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, express

I have created an app in node.js with neo4j as my database. I can create a new user and login, I can see that my sessions is created when the user is authenticated. The problem is that when I try to use res.locals.user and access it in my view with {{#if user}} to restrict access to unauthenticated users, it does not work and I cannot see the logout link even after I am logged in.

Here is my code for app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session =require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
const routes = require('./routes');
const nconf = require('./config');
const setAuthUser = require('./middlewares/setAuthUser');
const neo4jSessionCleanup = require('./middlewares/neo4jSessionCleanup');
const writeError = require('./helpers/response').writeError;
const crypto = require('crypto');
const router = express.Router();


const uuid = require('node-uuid');
const randomstring = require("randomstring");
const _ = require('lodash');


var User = require('./models/neo4j/user');
var loginRequired = require('./middlewares/loginRequired');
var dbUtils = require('./neo4j/dbUtils');

const app = express();


  // Body Parser middleware
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  var api = express.Router();

app.use(nconf.get('api_path'), api);

// Flash middleware
app.use(flash());


  //api custom middlewares:
api.use(setAuthUser);
api.use(neo4jSessionCleanup);

  // Handlebars middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main'
  }));
  app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

  // static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//method override middleware
api.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// Express Session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));

// global variables
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.user = req.username || null;
    next();
});

// index route
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    const title = 'welcome1';
    res.render('index', {
        title: title
    });
});

// User Login Route
app.get('/users/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('users/login');
});


// User Register Route
    app.get('/users/register', (req, res) => {
        res.render('users/register');
  });

// User registration process
  app.post('/users/register',(req, res,next) => {
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;

    if (!username) {

      req.flash('error_msg', 'username field is required');
      res.redirect('/users/register');
    }
    if (!password) {

      req.flash('error_msg', 'password field is required');
      res.redirect('/users/register');
    }

    register(dbUtils.getSession(req), username, password, req, res)
      .then(response => {
        req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now registered');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
      })
      .catch(next);
  });

  //User Login Process

app.post('/users/login', (req, res, next) => {

  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  if (!username) {

    req.flash('error_msg', 'username field is required');
    res.redirect('/users/login');
  }
  if (!password) {

    req.flash('error_msg', 'password field is required');
    res.redirect('/users/login');
  }

  login(dbUtils.getSession(req), username, password, req, res)
    .then(response => {
      req.flash('success_msg', `${username}: You are now logged in`); 
      req.session.user = username;
      res.locals.user = username;
      console.log(`inside login ${username}`);
      res.redirect('/');
    })
    .catch(next);

});


// User Logout Route
app.get('/users/logout', (req, res) => {

  req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');
  res.redirect('/users/login');
  req.session.destroy();

});



//temp data


var register = function (session, username, password, req, res) {
  return session.run('MATCH (user:User {username: {username}}) RETURN user', {username: username})
    .then(results => {
      if (!_.isEmpty(results.records)) {

        req.flash('error_msg', 'Username already registered');
        res.redirect('/users/register');
      }
      else {
        return session.run('CREATE (user:User {id: {id}, username: {username}, password: {password}, api_key: {api_key}}) RETURN user',
          {
            id: uuid.v4(),
            username: username,
            password: hashPassword(username, password),
            api_key: randomstring.generate({
              length: 20,
              charset: 'hex'
            })
          }
        ).then(results => {
            return new User(results.records[0].get('user'));
          }
        )
      }
    });
};

var login = function (session, username, password, req, res) {

  return session.run('MATCH (user:User {username: {username}}) RETURN user', {username: username})
    .then(results => {
        if (_.isEmpty(results.records)) {

          req.flash('error_msg', 'Username does not exist');
          res.redirect('/users/login');
        }
        else {
          var dbUser = _.get(results.records[0].get('user'), 'properties');
          if (dbUser.password != hashPassword(username, password)) {

            req.flash('error_msg', 'Wrong password');
            res.redirect('/users/login');
          }

          console.log('logged in');
          let seid = req.session.id;
          console.log(`seid value ${seid}`);

        }
      }
    );
};



function hashPassword(username, password) {
  var s = username + ':' + password;
  return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(s).digest('hex');
}


const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

As you can see I have defined my global variables. My navbar partials looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary mb-3">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Vidjot</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
               {{#if user}}
                    <li class="nav-iten dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink">Video Ideas</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="/ideas" class="dropdown-item">Ideas</a>
                            <a href="/ideas/add" class="dropdown-item">Add Idea</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/users/logout" class="nav-link">Logout</a>
                </li>
                {{else}}
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/users/login" class="nav-link">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/users/register" class="nav-link">Register</a>
                </li>
                {{/if}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

What am I doing wrong??? Thanks in advance for any help.

I have edited my post to add the code for setAuthUser:

```
var writeError = require('../helpers/response').writeError;
var Users = require('../models/users');
var dbUtils = require('../neo4j/dbUtils');

module.exports = function setAuthUser(req, res, next) {
  var authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
  if (!authHeader) {
    req.user = {id: null};
    next();
  }
  else {
    var match = authHeader.match(/^Token (\S+)/);
    if (!match || !match[1]) {
      return writeError(res, {detail: 'invalid authorization format. Follow `Token <token>`'}, 401);
    }
    var token = match[1];

    Users.me(dbUtils.getSession(req), token)
      .then(user => {
        req.user = user;
        next();
      })
      .catch(next);
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you share the content of the file './middlewares/setAuthUser' please :)? Because you are setting up the local var 'user' in the 'login' post request middleware, but not any where else in what you shared. Thus, if you are doing so, I suspect it is in this specific file.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I have added the setAuthUser code as well.

Comment: Ok, so try to debug what contains the user variable after the promise resolved. Is it empty? Is it the expected result? Also, in your view, you may use 'if user.id' instead of 'if user' as you are setting user with and object which contains a null id by default.

Comment: I did a console.log on req.user, its not being called at all. I actually have adopted the neo4j exaple from their github. That example was based on APIs and this setAuthUser is part of that. As you can see in my app.js, I am converting the example to express based app without using the APIs and doing all the processing in the routes. That is why it is not actively being called.

Comment: I see, but actually it should be called. You are adding setuserAuth to the middleware stack of the app. Thus, I see one reason is that you never enter in the 'else' part of the middleware which means that your client does not send an Authorization header correctly. If the Users.me is never called, try to see in which part of the callback it passes.

Comment: can you show me how i should modify it?

Comment: Oh I just meant to do some debug / console.log to see in what part of the callback is executed. It will help us to know if the client is sending the token or not. And in the case of nope, then it is perfectly normal that Users.me is never executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169692/discussion-between-laudeon-and-amin-baig).